# Descendants to selected only

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

The Product Hierarchy consists of 3 levels:
**Category,
SubCategory**
and **Product**

I have firstly created a dynamic set **[Selected Products]**:

```
CREATE DYNAMIC SET [Selected Products] as (
EXISTING [Product].[Product].members - [Product].[Product].[All]
);
```

I have a **measure_** that is calculated as follows:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[MEASURES].[MyMeasure(%)_]
AS IIF([Measures].[Total] <> 0, [Measures].[SomeMeasure]/[Measures].[Total], NULL)
```

and it is used to calculate the following **measure**:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[MEASURES].[MyMeasure(%)]
AS
(
 IIF(
 [Product].[Product Hierarchy].CurrentMember IS [Product].[Product Hierarchy].[All]
,AVG([Selected Products],[MEASURES].[MyMeasure(%)_]),
AVG(Descendants([Product].[Product Hierarchy].currentmember,[Product].[Product Hierarchy].Levels('Product'),SELF)
        , [MEASURES].[MyMeasure(%)_])
)
)
```

Grand total calclation is fine as it takes all the **[Selected Products]**
Calculation on Product level is also fine.

The problem is when it comes to calculate on **Category** or **SubCategory** level when not all belonging products are selected. The returned values in fact are calculations for all belonging children and not **selected only**.

Is is possible to amend above Descendants() expression so it refers to [Selected Products] only?

How can I re write?